# ServerA can't access ServerB through UNC path. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

All my servers are in the same domain on the same network. ServerA cannot access ServerB through UNC path. However DNS resolves correctly for ServerB from ServerA. For example "ping ServerB" works as expected.

ServerB can reach ServerA through UNC path without any problem. Likewise all other servers and clients can reach ServerB through UNC path without any problem. The software firewall on ServerB is not turned on and there are no hardware firewalls getting in the way.

This makes no sense and I don't know how to troubleshoot it. Nothing shows up in the event logs of ServerA and ServerB has one event (repeatedly): Event ID: 3019, Source: MrxSmb.

ServerA is Server 2008 R2. ServerB is Server 2003 R2. I have other 2008 R2 servers that connect without any problem.

Comment: does \\ipaddressofserverb\sharename work?

Comment: Sorry for having neglected this post. The answer is yes. The IP address works.

Comment: Additionnally, can you access the share through \\server.fully.qualified.domain.name\sharename ?

Comment: @T.Fabre I have not experienced this problem a long time so I am going to delete the question. Hopefully you get this message so you know why the question is gone. -- Apparently I can't delete the question because of the answers. I'll try something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue cannot be solved any longer because the servers do not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't reach a computer's hostname / computer name, but you can ping its IP address, you have DNS problems.  Most likely you have duplicate DNS entries for the unreachable computer, and the short-term fix is to just delete the outdated entry.  Tweaking the expiration settings is the long-term fix, but it takes some reading to get it right (mostly because the terminology is pretty arcane).

Comment: Thanks for your response. A few points:

1. DNS does work. I can ping the hostname and the IP address will be returned.

2. There is only one A record and one PTR record for ServerB.

3. All other computers in the domain are able to resolve/access ServerB. If it were a DNS issue I believe this would affect the whole network but this is not the case.

To clarify my process, I'm using DNS Manager on my DC to check the records.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access a share in your UNC path, or just the server?  What about permissions on your share (the share you are attempting to access on ServerB)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1. Anything that uses the UNC path fails. But yes, specifically, I'm trying to access a share. 2. The permissions are OK. The error is "Path does not exist" vs "Access Denied". But besides that a user can access the share without a problem through the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Can ServerA access any other SMB resources via UNC? Is NetBIOS over TCP/IP enabled and verified working correctly on ServerA?

Comment: Yes, ServerA can access other resources via UNC. I have not messed with NetBIOS so it would be in its default state on Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Can ServerA access ServerB shares via UNC with FQN versus NetBIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if there is some drive mapping already.

To do that, open the explorer windows, then choose tools -> disconnect network drive.
Ins the list of connections check if there is already a connection to the server / drive that you're trying to do.

Then choose it and press ok to disable it.